# Losing space in text conversion

Tags: postgresql

This example, where intuition expects "foo bar",  shows the strange behaviour:

```
SELECT 'foo'|| '#'::char ||'bar'          -- char ok, foo#bar
SELECT 'foo'|| '#' ||'bar'                -- literal ok 
SELECT 'foo'|| '#'::text ||'bar'          -- text ok 

SELECT 'foo'|| ' '::char ||'bar'          -- STRANGE! LOSTING SPACE!
SELECT ('foo'|| ' '::char ||'bar')='foobar' -- yes, it is true... strange

SELECT 'foo'|| ' '::text ||'bar'          -- text OK
SELECT 'foo'|| (' '::char)::text ||'bar'  -- char-to-text lost!
SELECT 'foo'|| ' ' ||'bar'                -- literal OK
```

Why does PostgreSQL do that? It is not intuitive, and seems error-prone behaviour.

PS: where does the PostgreSQL guide say (it needs a red alert) something about this?

Comment: trailing spaces are treated as semantically insignificant and
 disregarded when comparing two values of type character. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html

Comment: Thanks @JakubKania ,  you found something in the guide (!). Well, let's say to the "guide managers" to **put in red** theses hidden comments :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of many reasons it's often recommended to stick with `varchar()` or, in Postgres `text` types instead.

SQL standard mandates that CHAR() values are padded with space to fill the remaining bytes. For instance:

```
'A'::CHAR(5)
```

Will result in `"A    "` being stored. Now if have another field of different length, but same content:

```
'A'::CHAR10 = 'A'::CHAR(5)
```

We would want this to say `TRUE`, right? So the spaces added for padding to fill the `CHAR()` have to be trimmed.

This is less of a Postgres question then it is a disk storage or sql standard question. Something has to be written to those bytes on the disk and `space` is the standard. Some DB's only trim for comparison or conversion, and others, like Postgres, trim for nearly any function.

Since you are casting a space to a `CHAR(1)` (1 being the default length when none is specified, although it doesn't matter for this quesstion) your space gets lost as padding. This is just one of the caveats of using `CHAR()`. It's a damned if you do, damned if you don't situation.

Instead cast that thing to a `VARCHAR()` or `TEXT` as they are nearly always superior types to `CHAR()`.

Noted in the Postgresql documentation:

> Tip: There is no performance difference among these three types, apart
>   from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a
>   few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a
>   length-constrained column. While character(n) has performance
>   advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage
>   in PostgreSQL; in fact character(n) is usually the slowest of the
>   three because of its additional storage costs and slower sorting. In
>   most situations text or character varying should be used instead.

Comment: Thanks, good explanation (!).  Hum... About PostgreSQL, it wasn't a [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) project-decision... Seems some "legacy workaround", not make sense in pg9+ nowadays,  and this parse-spaces is contrary of any CPU optimization with the  simplest internal representation... You show why *text* datatype is the simplest.  About pg-guide, let's say to the "guide managers" to **put in red** these hidden-strange-unexpected behaviour of *char* datatype.

Comment: Again, though, I don't think these are "strange". `CHAR()` has all sorts of caveats in every RDBMS that all come down to the necessary padding to fill bytes on the disk. It's not a CPU issue, but rather a data storage issue that then results in increased cpu because of the trimming that has to take place every time an operation is applied against the `CHAR()` typed field. Generally the only advantage of `char()` is decreased disk space for known length fields, but we are talking about 1-4 bytes, minus compression, so it's really just not worth it.

Comment: Good explanation again ;-)  thanks.  About "strange" is a personal point of view, I think the *orthogonality of "string types"* is most important tham simplify some  1990's applications/optimizations... Today the risk of confusion (in a development/support team), in my opinion, lost any use of `char()` datatype.

Comment: I'll agree with you there. As is so often the case with DB related stuff, if you don't know your DB down to how it writes it's data to the disk, then you are going to run into spooky behavior and since folks that are concentrated more on the UI are probably more concerned with speed, user stories, design, and the metadata, the gotcha's of data storage and other machine-level stuff is understandably overlooked. Sometimes strange behavior just comes down to the bits and bytes underlying it all.